# Auto login user in windows operating system when system restarts?

Tags: c#

I can create a windows user as it is mentioned in the link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306273/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-local-system-by-using-directory-services-and)

so after creating the user, can i tell system to login with that particular username and password?
I shouldn't have to login manually. is it possible to do?

Manually we can do it.
You can use the registry to auto login a computer. The key you need is:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

Change `AutoAdminLogon` to `1`.

Set `DefaultUserName` and `DefaultPassword` to the accounts username and password.

If the values don't exist just create them. Usually `AutoAdminLogon` and `DefaultUserName` are already there but you may have to create DefaultPassword.

How we can do the same with c# and managed registry classes?

```
HOpe this method will work for xp


 public static void WriteDefaultLogin(string usr, string pwd)
    {
        //creates or opens the key provided.Be very careful while playing with 
        //windows registry.
        RegistryKey rekey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon");

        if (rekey == null)
            Console.WriteLine
                ("There has been an error while trying to write to windows registry");
        else
        {
            //these are our hero like values here
            //simply use your RegistryKey objects SetValue method to set these keys
            rekey.SetValue("AutoAdminLogon", "1");
            rekey.SetValue("DefaultUserName", usr);
            rekey.SetValue("DefaultPassword", pwd);
        }
        //close the RegistryKey object
        rekey.Close();
    }
```

but will this work for all windows OS?
Waht should i change to make it work for all windows OS? especially W10.